# "packages" error when doing update-package in vs 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

When i run the command

```
Update-Package <packagename> -version <packageversion> -IgnoreDependencies -IncludePreRelease -FileConflictAction Overwrite
```

I get the error

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with respect to project 'someproject', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages.
Resolving actions install multiple packages
Update-Package : packages
At line:1 char:15
+ Update-Package <<<<  <packagename> -version <packageversion> -IgnoreDependencies -IncludePreRelease -FileConflictAction Overwrite
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

What does `Update-Package : packages` mean?

I am working in visual studio 2015 with nuget package manager 3.4.4

Comment: Is this error occurs with one specific package or for all packages updates? I run your command with my NuGet Package Manager 3.4.4 to update the bootstrap package, which is updated successful. Please tell us which package do you want to update?

Comment: I am running it for a custom internal company package. It is not something you would know.

Comment: *The package name is not something you would know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was to do an uninstall and install of the package in question instead of doing an update-package for the projects where the update was failing.

Comment: Nice to hear. Probably fresh installation of your package fixes `PackageIdentity` for some of the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem [#1996](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1996) in NuGet which happens during package update. Seems your `packages` message problem is the other reincarnation of this known problem.

According to the NuGet [sources](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/b335ef98b50bffe1d5e07a987e881d4dd9994f2f/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.PackageManagement/NuGetPackageManager.cs#L1072) something wrong with `PackageIdentity`.

Comment: Actually packages is not the name of my package. I have a different package name. If you look at what i said i was running as command, you will see Update-Package <packagename> -version <packageversion> -IgnoreDependencies -IncludePreRelease -FileConflictAction Overwrite

Comment: @JayJayJay Could you please post an exact command you've executed?

Comment: I cant give you the exact package name because it is a name that is internal to our company.

Comment: This is the command that I executed :
 Update-Package <packagename> -version <packageversion> -IgnoreDependencies -IncludePreRelease -FileConflictAction Overwrite

Comment: @JayJayJay Does it look like: `Update-Package anyname  -version 1.0.0 -IgnoreDependencies -IncludePreRelease -FileConflictAction Overwrite`?

Comment: @JayJayJay Please check my updated answer, may be it will help you somehow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120974/discussion-between-jay-jay-jay-and-nikita).

Answer (score 0):

If you run Update-Package from the package manager console it will tell you a particular package couldn't be found in the repository.

Remove that package from your packages.config file and re-locate the package through the package manager to add it again.

This can happen if a package with a particular version was targeted and removed from the repository